# Add item to cart python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, bots

I'm trying to write a program in python to automate the purchasing procedure of some object on https://www.zalando.it/.
I've already written something that works with selenium but it is slower than requests.
So I was wondering if there was a way to add an item to the cart and maybe complete the checkout process via python requests.
The first question is: how do I know which parameters or data I should pass in requests?
In general, how do I determine what to put in the payload?

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36'})

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36'
    }
login = {
    'email' : 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'secret':'mypassword'
    }

payload = {
    "cartActionProductBrand": "Nike Sportswear",
    "cartActionProductIsSale": 0,
    "cartActionProductName": "AIR FORCE 1 '07 LV8 - Sneakers basse - white/black/game royal",
    "cartActionProductPrice": "109.99",
    "cartActionProductSize": "47",
    "cartActionProductSku": "NI112O0M9-A120125000",
    "event": "addToCart",
    "flowId": "SZSnGMU4lwR60woT",
    "host": "www.zalando.it",
    "pathname": "/nike-sportswear-air-force-1-07-lv8-sneakers-basse-whiteblackgame-royal-ni112o0m9-a12.html",
    "referrer": "https://www.zalando.it/scarpe-uomo/",
    "accept_language": "it-IT"
   
    }


post = s.post("https://accounts.zalando.com/api/login", headers=headers, json=login)
print(post.content)

addToCart = s.post("https://www.zalando.it/api/rr/e", headers=headers, json=payload)  

cart = s.get("https://www.zalando.it/cart/", headers=headers)
print(cart.text)
```

Comment: Probably the best way to go about such a problem is to try to buy the said item, while also inspecting the 'networking' tab in your browser. This way you can see what kind of data is being sent as the payload, the rest is really just a guessing game of what to include.

Comment: @Jakub Sowa take a look at my edit

Answer (score 1):

When i need to do some stuff like this, I open my browser(Chrome), inspect element, network tab and analyze all requests made from site. From here I get all info that i need; the URL, the method, the data passed, exc...

[image]

Comment: I can't find "headers" section

Comment: @LuigiV. by clicking on single request (the highlighted blue at left) doesn't show up nothing?

Comment: take a look at my edit

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think this question is not related to Python or `requests` but to REST API from Zalando. As far as I know, Zalando does have a [documented REST API](https://developers.merchants.zalando.com/docs/).

It also covers also your specific problem: https://developers.merchants.zalando.com/docs/orders-api.html

Comment: take a look at my edit